# Auto generation of array(string)

Tags: scala

I want to generate an array of alphabet values of length `k`.

E.g: let's say `k=2` (run time input)

```
//k = Length of each string
```

I want an

```
array [string] : ("aa","bb","cc","dd",..."zz")
```

If `k=3`

```
("aaa","bbb",...)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can start with an `Array` and build its elements.

```
Array.tabulate(26)(x => (x+'a').toChar.toString * k)
```

Or you can start with the elements and then transition to an `Array`.

```
('a' to 'z').map(_.toString * k).toArray
```